# The dimension of a complex vector space seen as a real space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have problem with the following: Let $V_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ complex vector space whose dimension is "$n$" and whose basis is $B=${$\vec{x_1},...,\vec{x_n}$}

- What is the dimension of $V$ if $V$ was seeing like a real vector space, calculate a basis of it.
- Let $V$ the endomorphism that is defined like $J: V_n(\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow V_n(\mathbb{C})\ / J(\vec{V})=i\vec{v}$. Calculate its change matrix basis if $V$ is seeing like a real vector space in the last basis calculated.

I don't know how I can prove it.

Comment: Hint:  for the first part, you know the $\vec{x_k}$ are a basis over $\mathbb C$.  So I can write a general vector $\vec v$ using linear combinations of the form $\sum \lambda_k \vec{x_k}$ where each $\lambda_k$ is complex. But then we can write  $\lambda_k = a_k + b_k i$ where $a_k$ and $b_k$ are real.  That should tell you what basis to use over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: sooo a basis of $V$ was $B_{V}=${$\vec{x_1},..., \vec{x_n},i\vec{x_1},...,i \vec{x_n}$} ¿?¿? lol

Comment: and its dimension if I consider that was "$2n$"

Comment: Good.  And with an explicit basis in mind, it should be easy to compute the desired matrix from part #2.

Comment: good... thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first, question, consider the more [general situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Field_extensions).

Suppose $\Bbb K$ is a subfield of a field $\Bbb F$. Then $\Bbb F$ may be regarded as a vector space over $\Bbb K$. Now, if $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F$, then $V$ may also be regarded as a vector space over $\Bbb K$. The dimensions of these vector spaces are related by the formula
$$ 
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}
\dim_{\Bbb K}(V)=\dim_{\Bbb F}(V)\cdot\dim_{\Bbb K}(\Bbb F)\tag{1}
$$
*Exercise.* Prove this assuming all the dimensions are finite.

Now, in our case we have
\begin{align*}
\Bbb K &= \Bbb R & \Bbb F &= \Bbb C & V &= \Span_{\Bbb C}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}
\end{align*}
What does (1) tell us about $\dim_{\Bbb R}V$?

Comment: @Hayden Of course I'd mess up arrows. I think I fixed it.

Comment: Great, thanks! +1

Comment: Is there construction that implements this map for an arbitrary n vector over $\mathbb{C}$ to the 2n vector over $\mathbb{R}$?